# Assembly problem/Fix the code so it can print 2 or more digit numbers as a result

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data
msg1 db 'The sum is:',0xa
lng1 equ $-msg1

section .bss
sum resb 3  ; Reserve 3 bytes for the sum (up to 255)

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov al, '8'  ; First number
sub al, '0'

mov bl, '4'  ; Second number
sub bl, '0'

add al, bl   ; al = 12 (Sum of 8 and 4)

; Split the sum into digits
mov bl, 10   ; Divider for separating digits
xor ah, ah   ; Clear ah before division
div bl       ; al = 1 (quotient), ah = 2 (remainder)

; Convert digits to ASCII and store in reverse order
add ah, '0'  ; Convert units digit to ASCII
mov [sum+1], ah  ; Store the units digit (2)

add al, '0'  ; Convert tens digit to ASCII
mov [sum], al   ; Store the tens digit (1)

; Print the message
mov edx, lng1
mov ecx, msg1
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 80h

; Print the sum
mov edx, 2      ; Length of the sum to print
mov ecx, sum    ; Start from the tens digit
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 80h

mov eax, 1
int 80h
```

Im trying to make it so it prints double digit numbers bigger than 18. I cant figure how to properly make the additions with integers bigger than 9.

Comment: `mov al, 123` for a 3-digit number as an immediate.  If you want to start with a multi-character string of ASCII digits, you need to multiply the earlier ones by their place-value and add them up.  Your printing code should be fine for results up to 99.